# Effect of weight perturbations on eigen values

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I have a dynamical system of coupled differential equations:

$\dot{X}$ = -X + S( AX + BI)

where X = 7x1 vector, A = 7x7 and B = 7x1 vector. S(x) is a nonlinear sigmoid function.

I want to find the trend of how the eigen values (at a given fixed point) change with perturbations in A and B. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $det[C] = \lambda_{1}*\lambda_{2}*...*\lambda_{n}$ maybe there is a relationship you can parse out there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I assume you mean det[A] by det[C] here. I cannot do this because: a) A and B together has around 20 free parameters, which I should consider as variables and there is no way to find a closed form expression for det[A] or det[B] b) Wouldnt my eigen values depend on both A and B ? The system being non-linear and all ?

Comment: Lets say you have a 4x4 matrix of nonlinear equations C.  $det[C] = f_{1}*f_{4} - f_{2}*f_{3}$ and furthermore we know by the property of eigen values $f_{1}*f_{4} - f_{2}*f_{3} = \lambda_{1}*\lambda_{2}*\lambda_{3}*\lambda_{4}$.  This might be a direction to go or not. A 7x7 matrix gets a little hairy on the determinant.